# Cannot find 'MVC Layout' option

Tags: sitecore

I am just starting to learn about Sitecore development. Following instructions from a tutorial, and instructions were to create a 'MVC Layout', however my local instance doesn't seem to show the option. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Missing 'MVC Layout' option]

Comment: I see controllers, layouts, models. It looks like you are only missing views

Comment: MVC Layout is just a command template that presents a wizard, allowing you to create your CSHTML file live on the system. In a typical system this makes no sense as you will create this file yourself. There's a rule that defines its presence, here: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Insert Options/Rules/MVC Layouts`

Answer (score 2):

You could still use the same 'Layout' template to specify a cshtml file as layout. Sitecore will be able to identify the type of layout using the extension. Sitecore does not have a MVC specific 'MVC Layout" template.
[image]